# How to insert to a table if there exist a value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have tried this

```
INSERT into examqst set qno=1, qst="aa" ,qan1="a" , qan2="B", qan3="C", qan4="d", qant="A", qtype=0, examid=1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM examname  where examid=1 and s_id=10);
```

I want to insert to **examqst** only if there is a row **examid** in **examname** table and **s_id** in **examname** have a perticilar value

Comment: Sorry, but the syntax for the INSERT-operator  is totally different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could an `INSERT INTO...SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO examqst (qno, qst, qan1, qan2, qan3, qan4, qant, qtype, examid)
SELECT 1, 'aa', 'a', 'B', 'C', 'd', 'A', 0, 1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM examname WHERE examid = 1 AND s_id = 10);
```

Comment: how can i do same for update?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: got the ans 
UPDATE examqst set qno="", qst="", qan1="", qan2... 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM examname WHERE examid = 1 AND s_id = 10);